# css and checkall checkbox not working in datatable and bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

im using bootstrap and integrating it with jquery DataTable. my problem is, i make a check all checkbox. its doesnt apply on the first page. but others page it checked. and the css seem not working too. anyone out there face this problem too? see the picture below.

[image]

and im using this code..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            'columnDefs': [{
                'targets': 8,
                'orderable': false,
            }]
        });

        // Handle click on "Select all" control
        $('#example-select-all').on('click', function () {
            // Check/uncheck all checkboxes in the table
            var rows = table.rows({ 'search': 'applied' }).nodes();
            $('input[type="checkbox"]', rows).prop('checked', this.checked);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

we also use the function of the project; you may be do this:

```
    // Handle click on "Select all" control
    $('#example-select-all').change(function () {
        // Check/uncheck all checkboxes in the table
        var checkbox=$('#example input[type="checkbox"]');
        var checked = $(this).is(":checked");
        checkbox.each(function(){
            if (checked) {
                $(this).attr("checked", true);
            } else {
                $(this).attr("checked", false);
            }
        })
    });
```

Comment: tq bro for your help... actually mine is working fine.. only the first page of the datatable isnt working... u can see the image up there..